# Xamarin Forms Tabbed Page Trigger properties not working

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, font-awesome, eventtrigger, tabbedpage

I'm trying to follow this [sample](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/tabs-and-triggers/)
by using font awesome as icon for the tabbed page and use the triggers to change font color
but when I want to apply the style using font awesome I got an error that Property="IsChecked" does not exist for the target.
I noticed in the sample they are using shells how could I replicate that example using regular tabbed pages?

on the app.XAML I have the following

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" 
            x:Key="FontAwesomeSolid">
            <On Platform="Android" 
            Value="Font5Solid.otf#Regular" />
            <On Platform="iOS" 
            Value="FontAwesome5Free-Solid" />
         </OnPlatform>
         <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" 
            x:Key="FontAwesomeRegular">
            <On Platform="Android" 
            Value="Font5Regular.otf#Regular" />
            <On Platform="iOS" 
             Value="FontAwesome5Free-Regular" />
          </OnPlatform>
```

For the tabbed page I have the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabbedPage x:Name="Tab" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="pages.Views.HomeTabbedPage">
    <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->

    <TabbedPage.Resources>
          <ResourceDictionary>
     <Style TargetType="Tab" x:Key="FollowTab">
                <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger TargetType="TabbedPage"
                         Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Icon" >
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <FontImageSource FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeRegular}" Glyph="&#xf004;"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger TargetType="Tab" 
                         Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Icon" >
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <FontImageSource FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" Glyph="&#xf004;"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
  </ResourceDictionary>
    </TabbedPage.Resources>

    <ContentPage Title="sample page"  />
    
</TabbedPage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replicate that in a normal `TabbedPage` you can try these steps:

1 - Create a converter to check `TabbedPage.CurrentPage` type:

```
public class SelectedTabTypeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        if (!(value is Page))
            throw new ArgumentException("Expected value to be of type " + nameof(Page), nameof(value));

        // if value is a NavigationPage check against its RootPage
        if (value is NavigationPage navPage)
            return navPage.RootPage?.GetType();

        return value.GetType();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
        => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

2 - Add the `x:Name` attribute to the TabbedPage so we can reference it latter:

```
<TabbedPage x:Name="MyTabbedPage" ...
```

3 - Add the converter resource to `TabbedPage.Resources`:

```
  <TabbedPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <converters:SelectedTabTypeConverter x:Key="SelectedTabTypeConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </TabbedPage.Resources>
```

4 - Add the pages and the `DataTriggers`:

```
  <TabbedPage.Children>
    <!-- Normal page tab default values -->
    <views:OnePage Title="Page1">
      <views:OnePage.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger 
            TargetType="views:OnePage"
            Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyTabbedPage}, Path=CurrentPage, Converter={StaticResource SelectedTabTypeConverter}}" 
            Value="{x:Type views:OnePage}">
          <Setter Property="Title" Value="Page1 Selected" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </views:OnePage.Triggers>
    </views:OnePage>

    <!-- NavigationPage tab -->
    <NavigationPage Title="Page2">
      <x:Arguments>
        <views:TwoPage />
      </x:Arguments>
      <NavigationPage.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger 
            TargetType="NavigationPage" 
            Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyTabbedPage}, Path=CurrentPage, Converter={StaticResource SelectedTabTypeConverter}}" 
            Value="{x:Type views:TwoPage}">
          <Setter Property="Title" Value="Page2 Selected" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </NavigationPage.Triggers>
    </NavigationPage>
  </TabbedPage.Children>
```